# Python how to search value in one csv based on another csv - pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a program that needs to search a csv file for matching values in another csv file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

listings = pd.read_csv("data/listings.csv")
inventoryValue = pd.read_csv("data/inventoryValue.csv")

#get rid of rows with empty values in column 'Item Number'

listings['Item Number'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
listings.dropna(subset=['Item Number'], inplace=True)

#get rid of rows with empty values in column 'AvgCost'

inventoryValue['Avg Cost'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
inventoryValue.dropna(subset=['Avg Cost'], inplace=True)


#here how can I search for all of the rows in inventoryValue[Item Number] based on Listings[Item Number]
```

So basically I need to use Item Number column in listings to find rows with matching Item Number in inventoryValue, from there I can get the columns I need in Inventory Value and save the file.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want can be achieved using `isin`. This method is used to filter data frames by selecting rows with having a particular value in a particular column.

In your case,  you can create a `list` that contains all the unique values of **Listings['Item Number']**, and then check which of the elements are present in **inventoryValue['Item Number']**, and return back a reduced dataframe:

```
my_list = listings['Item Number'].unique().tolist()
new_inventoryValue = inventoryValue[inventoryValue['Item Number'].isin(my_list)]
```

Which will return back a smaller dataframe (row-wise), with all the columns, but your 'Iterm Number'' column will have only the elements in `my_list`.

Comment: Yes that seems to be what I need! Do you have any idea why new_inventoryValue has around 2000 less rows than the original listings.csv?

Comment: That is a question that can potentially have many answers. One thing you could do is check the common elements in the 2 columns, if there are many common elements, then the resulting df should be a bit smaller, if there are many differences, then the resulting df should have much less rows. You can get the common elements using: ```[i for i in inventoryValue['Item Number'].unique() if i in listings['Item Number'].unique()]```

Comment: That makes sense, what confuses me is that inventoryValue.csv should contain all of the Item Numbers as the listings.csv, so the resulting frame should be the same as listings. 

Edit:
there are also no duplicates

Comment: Yes exactly, if they contain the same item numbers the resulting dataframe should be the same. Can you post a sample of your data so that I can have a look? I am afraid I can't help more without looking at it. Check for inconsistencies in spelling, extra spaces, etc..?

Comment: I found the problem in the data, so all seems to be working smooth now :) Thank you very much for your help. I'm more familiar with javascript and php, I figured that this project with csv's would be ideal to get started with python.

Comment: I also transitioned from R to Python a year ago, I know the feeling. Glad I could help. Happy learning.

Comment: Do you know how I can have new_inventoryValue include the rest of the columns from listings?

Comment: I think you mean merge the 2 datasets together, as they were separated before. Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101. It should be enough to follow and get your desired outcome. If you can't, let me know and I'll try to help you out. Thanks.